# Current Storage requirements

Tags: fast-sync

Very new to this. following teething problems and multiple restarts I'm running a fast sync with max cache.

I'm starting to down load the block chain in fast syncmode, whats the current storage requirements of the block chain?

This is going on an M2 NVMe with about 420 gb beside the OS.

I started a light down load that didnt look like it was doing any thing. so I impatiently stopped and started the fast.

How much space would the current light sync consume?

TIA, Appologies if this is a repeat. I have searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "fast" size is close to 120GB right now. You can see it on [this chart](https://etherscan.io/chart2/chaindatasizefast)

The "light" size is less than 1GB, but the node needs to use "fast" or "full" nodes for some operations. You haven't seen any activity, most probably because your instance couldn't find any "fast" nodes to serve it.

Comment: Thankyou for this. It's reassuring. I dont want to be downloading for a couple of days only to start again. Currently at 140000 in the chain and 41.9 GB Does this sound about right?

Comment: Np. Please accept my answer so that others will know it answered the question. Thanks

Comment: thankyou, please forgive me, im a total noob, having issues and really trying hard not to ask stupid questions, im flogging this off to no avail. I bought ether and put it in my ethereum wallet by mistake instead of my ledger. no the transactions are taking days and not moving. sob story lol. Ill com back when ive given up or learnt more. Thanks again